# Add all of the classes in a package in web.xml resteasy providers

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have several `ExceptionMapper` classes in `mapper` package and would like to add all of them in web.xml without writing them one by one. Is it possible? Something like

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>mapper.*</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins if I understand what container means I'm running on Tomcat 8.5

Comment: In that case you should be able to just annotate each one with `@Provider` and the project should scan for them. You'll need to remove that context parameter.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I have but unfortunately it doesn't scan providers automatically. I think I've read in another thread that that feature isn't available anymore

Comment: It should work. Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d5e191. You might just need to add that dependency.